# "Timbre" or "sello"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, españa, sustantivos

I'm slightly confused as to the translation of the word "stamp". European Spanish have the word **timbres** used in correlation with **stamps** (plural), and for example a Google picture search for *timbres* will show mostly stamps, and for example the Royal Mint of Spain is called the Fábrica Nacional de Moneda y Timbre (Factory of Money and Stamps). And in French, *timbre* refers to regular postal stamps.

Am I correct in assuming *timbre* is more of related to English terms such as "rubber stamped" or "signed", i.e. approved by a higher authority whereas *sello* is the more modern term for (postal) stamps?

Or is this a terrible example of a word where the translation (doorbell) refers to the physical stamp, and have nothing to do with (ringing) a doorbell, and the internet is just widely misleading me?

Comment: I suppose this might vary from one place to another.  But in Mexico, if I ring your doorbell, that's *timbre*, and if I send a snail mail letter, I put postage (one or more *timbres*) on it.  It's just a word with two unrelated meanings (which is not a terrible thing!).  // If a bureaucratic office puts a stamp of approval on some piece of paper, that would be *sello*.  Think "Good Housekeeping Seal of Approval."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inicialmente la palabra "timbre" tenía como único significado el que tiene aún en [heráldica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre_(her%C3%A1ldica)): *"la insignia que se coloca sobre el escudo de armas para indicar el grado de nobleza"*. No aparece con otro significado en los diccionarios (ni de la RAE ni otros) hasta la segunda mitad del s. XIX.
En lo que a España respecta, dentro de toda la parafernalia que conforma el [escudo de armas oficial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escudo_de_Espa%C3%B1a#Casa_de_Borb%C3%B3n_(1700-1808)), **el timbre sería la corona** (borbónica o mural, según) que va sobre el escudo:

[image]

De ahí, bien por metonimia o bien por ser la corona el elemento más destacado, **en el s. XIX pasó a usarse "timbre" para referirse a los sellos** (los de estampar, en madera o metal) con los que se firmaba la documentación oficial; y de ahí, nuevamente por metonimia, pasó a significar *también* la marca en sí que dejaban estos sellos con el escudo real, dentro de los cuales el timbre solía ser el elemento del escudo más fácil de distinguir:

[image]

Nótese que en el documento de la imagen, de 1810, se usa la palabra "sello", y no "timbre". Como digo, este significado de "timbre" llegó después, a raíz de la utilización del escudo y timbre reales como elementos compositivos en los sellos oficiales.

La [Fábrica Nacional de Moneda y Timbre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1brica_Nacional_de_Moneda_y_Timbre) surgió a finales del XIX como fusión de dos organismos previos: la Casa de la Moneda y la Fábrica del Sello. Por entonces ya estaba más o menos establecido el uso de "timbre" como sinónimo de "sello oficial", y por tanto esa fue la denominación elegida para la nueva institución, encargada de fabricar tanto las monedas y billetes, como los sellos (timbres) oficiales que usaban las administraciones.

Con posterioridad, se fueron sustituyendo estas marcas estampadas por trocitos de papel que podían comprarse en establecimientos autorizados, lo cual aligeraba un poco los trámites burocráticos.
En parte porque durante los 40 años de dictadura el timbre dejó de ser un elemento destacado en los sellos, y en parte porque paulatinamente se fueron introduciendo diseños más variados, el empleo de "timbre" para referirse a los sellos cayó en desuso al no ser ya el timbre un elemento destacado en los sellos oficiales.

**Hoy en día, prácticamente nadie usa "timbre" para referirse a un sello, ni postal ni de los otros.** Su uso en ese sentido solo se ve en contextos históricos o en heráldica.
En el resto de casos, **"timbre" siempre se refiere al instrumento que produce un sonido para avisar de algo**: el timbre de la puerta, el timbre del recreo.

---

PD: Quería mencionar que, en mi caso, una [búsqueda por `timbres` en Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=timbres&tbm=isch) me muestra... timbres. No sé cómo lo ha hecho OP para que le muestre sellos.

Comment: Claro, gracias. P.S. https://i.imgur.com/sekf9Un.jpg (Google Inglesa, links están en francés.) :)

Comment: yeah, I realised once I looked at all the URLs for the results were in .fr. I didn't notice that originally.

Answer (score 4):

In Spain, *[timbre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZlAmr0b)* is mostly used with its first meaning (according to the RAE's dictionary):

> Small device used to call or notify by the rapid emission of intermittent sounds.

I also know, but seldom use, the meaning of the word in the context of musical instruments (6th meaning):

> Quality of the sounds determined by the perceptive effect produced in the listeners.

But I never use it with the meaning of "stamp" or "signed by an authority", those are very formal meanings reserved for very specific purposes (see 2nd to 5th meanings). If you want to refer to the stamps you put on an envelope to send a mail, we always use *[sello](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XUsdYcB)* as a shortened form of *sello postal*. In fact, the definition of *sello* includes the word *timbre*:

> Trozo pequeño de papel, con timbre oficial de figuras o signos grabados, que se pega a ciertos documentos para darles valor y eficacia.

Translated:

> Small piece of paper, with official stamp of figures or engraved signs, which sticks to certain documents to give them value and effectiveness.

That makes me think that *timbre* is the *stamping* on the stamp, and *sello* is the stamp itself.

Comment: `the stamping on the stamp` that actually make a lot of sense. Specially if we consider that before postal stamps, it was just a (physical) ink stamp on the letters (and still is, on top of the physical stamps). Thanks!